# Automatically create an Azure DevOps Organization with an ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

Since it is not possible to create an organization with the DevOps Rest API and the SDK for organizations is still in preview and not functional, we currently try to programmatically create an organization with an ARM template.

In the Azure Portal, it is possible to create a new organization with an ARM template like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/Microsoft.Resources.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "organizationName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "organizationIdentifier": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": ""
    },
    "administrator": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": ""
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('organizationIdentifier')]",
      "type": "microsoft.visualstudio/account",
      "location": "West Europe",
      "description": "[parameters('organizationName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-02-26",
      "properties": {
        "operationType": "Create",
        "accountName": "[parameters('organizationIdentifier')]",
        "ownerUpn": "[parameters('administrator')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately we couldn't find a solution to create this within a C# Azure Function programmatically, since the SDK would want a resource group, which doesn't make sense in this context. Is there a way to do this or is it simply not possible to create an organization automatically at this point?

Comment: Looking at the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/visualstudio/accounts/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP), it seems you need to specify a resource group anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of now there is **no** ways to create an DevOps organization using REST API.

The way to create Azure DevOps Organization is **Manual creation** or using **ARM Template**.

Using ARM Template, you have to specify the **Resource**   name as a parameter. That is also we need to mention the **Organization** Name before deploying the ARM Template.

As of now the REST API is available for some of the [services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

#### References

-[Automating organization and project creation in Azure DevOps](https://tobiasfenster.io/automating-organization-and-project-creation-in-azure-devops) Blog gives the clear view